# How to make javascript function work in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code in js:

```
document.getElementById("collection").innerHTML = `
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center" class="mb-4">
    <h1>Collection of ${bottleData.length} bottles</h1>
</div>
${bottleData.map(bottleTemplate).join('')}
`
```

And would like to have the `${bottleData.length}` function work in HTML.
The HTML code is here: https://github.com/MarvelousMartin/absolut-vodka-collection/blob/master/index.html

Is there some way?
Thanks.

Comment: That should work. Show the full code, including how `bottleData` is set.

Comment: can you share you ```HTML``` code so we can help.

Comment: Template literals do not create live functions. When the length of `bottleData` changes, the HTML won't change automatically. It just uses the value of `bottleData.length` at the time you assign it.

Comment: `bottleData` is just a `const` set in JS that includes JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file there should be a eventlistener to make the function work in html.

Suppose you have a Button and want a Function to Work on click

HTML :

```
<button onclick="Test()">Event Listener in HTML</button>
<script src="Path_to_your_script_file"></script>
```

Js :

```
function Test() {
    document.write("<h1>HTML code can be written Inside Js like this</h1>")
    document.write("<h1>HTML can be written inside document.write('') in Js</h1>")
 }
```

[See in Codepen for extra Reference](https://codepen.io/SheikAhamedIqbal/pen/dyWrwmg)